# Create symlinks to results of folder search from get-childitem command in powershell and name them after foldername

Tags: powershell

Kind of new to powershell and am trying to search a top level folder for any subfolders that might contain a folder named "training" within them, and then create symlinks in a target folder for each result using the name of the parent folder that "training" folder is in..... Sorry if that sounds confusing.

So basically, a search of "C:\company" where if the "c:\company\test" folder had a "training" subfolder in it, the script would write a symlink to the destination named "test" but pointing to "c:\company\test\training".

I have a working command to find the folder search results I want

`$folder = gci "TopSearchedFolder" -recurse -filter "training" | Select-Object Parent`

And from searching it appears the following would create the symlinks..

`New-Item -Itemtype SymbolicLink -path "SymlinkDestinationFolder"`

I'm just not sure how to pipe the search results into the creation of the symlinks. Should I be using a For-each or something? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have PowerShell 5.1 or newer.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "TopSearchedFolder" -Filter 'training' -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "SymlinkDestinationFolder" -Name $_.Parent -Value $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help. So if I understand correctly, $_. is just a carry through of the piped variable and you can select elements of that variable specifically? Thanks again.

Comment: @bjones306 Yes, that is exactly what the [$_ Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#_) is for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gci "TopSearchedFolder" -recurse -filter "training" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Parent|Foreach{
New-Item -Itemtype SymbolicLink -path "$($_)"
}
```

`$_` is the current item in pipeline, and `-ExpandProperty` to expand values only.

Comment: After creating a subfolder called "test" in the "TopSearchedFolder" with a "training" folder in it, the above produces the following error...... `New-Item : Test
At line:2 char:1
+ New-Item -Itemtype SymbolicLink -path "$($_)"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand`

Comment: So it's finding the correct subfolder that contained a test folder, but it doesn't appear to want to create the symlink.